# Where are the built in django template tags located?

Tags: django

I found a directory called template tags in the django repo, but I do not see the template tags I'm looking for.  Specifically, this one:

```
{{ testdate | date:'m-d-Y, H:i a' }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The source code you are looking for,

```
@register.filter(expects_localtime=True, is_safe=False)
def date(value, arg=None):
    """Format a date according to the given format."""
    if value in (None, ''):
        return ''
    try:
        return formats.date_format(value, arg)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            return format(value, arg)
        except AttributeError:
            return ''
```

You can find them in the defaultfilters.py file.

django -> django -> template -> defaultfilters.py

https://github.com/django/django/blob/ff05de760cc4ef4c7f188e163c722ec3bc1f0cbf/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L687

Comment: @gbrener Agreed, but the question itself asked for a link to a piece of code. Although I've edited the answer and added the source code of the functionality in question, to make the answer more descriptive

Comment: Great - thanks for the edit. I've deleted my comment, since StackOverflow doesn't appear to support editing reviews.